# Why can't I declare a function before render in React?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, methods

So my code works, but if I move handleClick() to the render, It will throw an error. Same if I try to declare a function like

`var handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({reservationVisible: true})
        console.log(this.state.reservationVisible)}`

outside render.

Also when I'm passing `handleClick()` as a prop, I need to call `{this.handleClick.bind(this)}` and when I'm using a function, declared inside render, `{handleClick.bind(this)` is enough. I don't really understand why. Where should I declare functions then? Outside or inside render? Should I use functions or methods?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Room from './Room'
import Form from './Form'

class Rooms extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {reservationVisible: false}
  }

    handleClick(e){
        this.setState({reservationVisible: true})
        console.log(this.state.reservationVisible)
      }

  render(){


      let rooms = [
        {
          roomNumber: '1',
          type: 'Cool room',
          price: '130 $',
          goods: ['radio', 'phone']
        },
        {
          roomNumber: '2',
          type: 'Cozy Room ',
          price: '165 $',
          goods: ['radio', 'phone, tv']
        },
        {
          roomNumber: '3',
          type: 'Dirty Room',
          price: '130 $',
          goods: ['balcony', 'phone']
        },
        {
          roomNumber: '4',
          type: 'Like Real Dirty Room',
          price: '90 $',
          goods: ['fridge', 'phone', 'balcony']
        }
      ]

      let getElements = (room, i) => {
        return(
          <Room
            key={i}
            roomNumber={room.roomNumber}
            type={room.type}
            price={room.price}
            goods={room.goods.map(good => good + ", ")}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          />
        )
      };
      let roomsMapped = rooms.map(getElements);

    return(
      <div>
        {roomsMapped}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Rooms
```

and the Room component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Room extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="room">
        <div className="image"><h1>Image nr {this.props.roomNumber}</h1></div>
        <div className="buttonGroup">
          <div className="button galleryButton">Gallery</div>
          <div className="button reserve" onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this)}> I'll take it</div>
        </div>
        <div className="info">
          <div className="topInfo">
            <span className="left">{this.props.type}</span>
            <span className="right">{this.props.price}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="additional">
            {this.props.goods}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Room
```

Comment: Remember that in `JSX`, any JavaScript (inside of your `render() return`) must be wrapped inside of `{}`. Your class functions should be declared outside of render as it is in your example.

Comment: @Dan 
Well, it would be good to know too, since I still haven't found a straight answer to that. But I'm more concerned about the functions and methods in this question

Comment: You can write a React function how you've done it, without arrow functions. You can also write them with arrow functions (just take off the `var` keyword). When using arrow functions, you do not need to use `.bind(this)` because arrow functions are lexically scoped, this means that they use your parent scope in this case that is `Rooms`. Using `bind()` changes the context of this to `Rooms` and registers your function on the class. Without the binding, `this` within your function would equal `undefined`.

Comment: And I don't have to `bind(this)` when I'm using `onClick`  inside `Room`, since it is passed as a prop and refers to `Rooms` `handleClick` whose context is `Rooms` because of the use of an arrow function, right?
 Why is it even needed? At which point not binding this would become a problem?

Comment: You pass a function down from `Rooms` to `Room`, you are passing it down by reference. Your `Rooms` component needs to `.bind()` as you are registering your function on that component. You're then using `props` to pass the function down by reference, inside of `Room` you need to just call `<div className="button reserve" onClick={this.props.onClick()}> I'll take it</div>`. Calling your prop Room `onClick` might be a bit confusing!

Comment: If you have `Chrome` download `React Dev Tools`, you can inspect your components, their props and their states to alleviate any confusion.

Comment: Thank you for that! Would you mind if I asked you another question? Should I keep my array out of render? Or it doesn't make any difference

Comment: You're welcome! In my opinion, it doesn't really matter. You could declare a function that returns your JSON object of `rooms` which could neaten up your application code but I don't think it's very important.